# \includegraphics: File not found

Tags: graphics

I am trying to insert an image with the graphicx package using LuaLaTeX. I receive an error that the file cannot be found. I get this whether I use the \graphicspath argument or include the complete path in \includegraphics. After reading all similar discussions I could find, I have arrived at this code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{Figures/}}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Century Gothic}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{ACTB Normalized.png}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

The error I receive is:

> LaTeX Warning: File `ACTB Normalized.png' not found on input line 10.
>
> ! Package luatex.def Error: File `ACTB Normalized.png' not found: using draft setting.
>
> See the luatex.def package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>   ...
>
> l.10 \includegraphics{ACTB Normalized.png}

I have also tried other image file formats including .jpg, .pdf, and .eps. Any insights on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you saved the file in folder named "Figures" ? Also try to avoid spaces in name of files... It is bad practice.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try adding `\usepackage{grffile}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turned out to be a very simple solution. Apparently it didn't like the space in the filename of my graphic. Removing spaces or using `grffile` package solves the problem. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 2):

Do not use accented characters or space in the file path

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is more a comment rather than an answer. Could you please elaborate on why using accented characters in file paths is bad given the example of the OP?